# Android Async Task exceptions handling

Tags: java, android

I am working on an android app, which has a async task. The task uses apache tika parsers to parse some documents and store it somewhere.The problem is parsing of some documents fail, due to certain ClassNotFound or NoClassDefFound exceptions. Exceptions are ok but how to catch any kind of exceptions including the one I mentioned above and proceed with other documents. No exception should be shown to users or app shouldn't crash.

can someone please help me with the above situation and suggest me the best approach to deal with it. Appreciate your time and help. Thanks

Comment: You probably need to use try {} catch in the doInBackground method.If you catch exception then return null. Or Include an error status in the AsyncTask return object. Then you can propagate the error back to UI if needed. If you could post the code of the AsyncTask in question it would help

Comment: Thanks @KevinLEGOFF for a quick reply. I did try and catch the exception, but it doesn't seem to catch the ClassNotFound or NoclassDefFound happening in apache library classes and it crashes the app.Here is the code snippet.

Comment: try {
                    parser.parse(stream, handler, metadata, context);
                } catch (TikaException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SAXException e2) {
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e3) {
                    e3.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        if (stream != null)
                            stream.close();
                    } catch (Exception e)

Comment: I ended up catching java.lang.Error for now. Please let me know if someone has a better approach for this.